# Take string if not empty not working as expected

Tags: kotlin

I have a fun that replaces comma with empty string. Then converts it to double. User can input only numbers and commas. After `replace` I want to take this string only if its not empty for conversion purposes. But although its empty `takeIf{}` doesnt seem to see it this way. When I enter only "," as first char in a string, the conversion fails throwing:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Scenario when entering `,` as first char.

```
replace(",", "")
    .takeIf {
        println(it) //prints nothing
        println(it.length) //prints 0
        if (isNotEmpty()) { // docs says that it checks if length > 0, which is not, so string is empty
            println("not empty") // still prints not empty
        } else {
            println("empty")
        }
        isNotEmpty()
    }?.toDouble()) // runs toDouble on empty string
```

Logs:

```
System.out: 0
System.out: not empty
```

Comment: there seems to be a missing piece... is this an extension function on `String`? Or should it be `if (it.isNotEmpty())`?

Comment: extension function

Comment: jesus it should be `it.isNotEmpty()`... need a coffe thanks!

Comment: you may be interested in [`String.toDoubleOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double-or-null.html) instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `replace` returns the adapted `String`, but does not alter the underlying string... So when you call `isNotEmpty()` you check for the initial/receiver `String` (which was `","`), but when you print the content or the length, you take the result of the replacement (`it`).

So if you use `it` consequently, it will work as you expect.

Note also that there exists [`toDoubleOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double-or-null.html) which just returns `null` if no double can be extracted from the `String`, e.g:

```
replace(",", "").toDoubleOrNull() // if it is not parseable, we get null
```

So you can spare even more characters and conditions in your code.